# Conversation and sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, verbs, sequence-of-tenses

"why didn't you tell me this sooner?I've given you/I gave you many chances to and everytime you have avoided/avoided answering me."
Which do you think is correct?

Comment: Why do you think one of them is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct grammar.

I gave you many chances. SIMPLE PAST

I have given you many chances. PAST PERFECT

The choice is stylistic and connotations will vary based on your variety of English. My bias on hearing the Past Perfect version leads me to think of John Cleese being domineering.